# Java Date strange behaviour

Tags: java, date

I have very strange behaviour of Java Date class:

```
    System.out.println(new Date().toGMTString());
    long l = 1332452310L;
    Date d = new Date(l);
    System.out.println(d.toGMTString());
```

Gives me

```
22 Mar 2012 22:00:42 GMT
16 Jan 1970 10:07:32 GMT
```

Why this happens?

Comment: What would you expect? the long-argument to the date constructor is the number of milliseconds since 1970, 1 Jan.

Comment: new Date gives now. A long parameter indicates the mseconds from 1970.

Comment: What did the documentation tell you when you consulted it?

Comment: Ssory, my bad. Late time %) I was confused by out of range error which I got without L param.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your long l is the time in seconds, you need to make it the time in milliseconds:

```
long l = 1332452310L * 1000L;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the number of seconds, rather than milliseconds, which you should.

Answer (score 0):

Date(long) expects milliseconds. Multiply your value by 1000 and check if you get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to times 1000 transfer from seconds to milliseconds to feed in the Data